# NoSuchMethodError in OSX but not Ubuntu

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu

I have a class that calls methods from another class. I compiled and ran it on Ubuntu 13.04 and it runs fine. On OSX 10.8.4, I get the following output:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Complex.equals(LComplex;)Z
    at ComplexTester.main(ComplexTester.java:11)

I tried running it in Eclipse, Netbeans and terminal and I get the same output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Complex**

```
public class Complex {

    private double real;
    private double imaginary;

    /**
     * 
     * @param real the real part of the Complex number
     * @param imaginary the imaginary part of the Complex number
     */
    public Complex(double newReal,double newImaginary){
        real=newReal;
        imaginary=newImaginary;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the real part of the Complex number
     */
    public double getReal(){
        return real;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return the imaginary part of the complex number
     */
    public double getImaginary(){
        return imaginary;
    }

    /**
     * gives real a new value
     * @param newReal the new value of real
     */
    public void setReal(double newReal){
        real=newReal;
    }

    /**
     * gives imaginary a new value
     * @param newImaginary the new value of Imaginary
     */
    public void setImaginary(double newImaginary){
        imaginary=newImaginary;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param x the new Complex object whose instance variables must be added to the old one
     * @return a new Complex object that is a combination of the parameters of both Complex objects
     */
    public Complex add(Complex x){
        Complex result=new Complex(x.getReal()+real,x.getImaginary()+imaginary);
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param other the Complex object being compared
     * @return true if both Complex objects have the same imaginary and real parts
     */
    public boolean equals(Complex other){
        return other.getImaginary()==imaginary && other.getReal()==real;
    }


}
```

**ComplexTester**

```
public class ComplexTester {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Complex x=new Complex(23.2,33.1);
        Complex y=new Complex(23.2,33.1);

        //test the equals method
        System.out.println(x.equals(y));
        System.out.println("Expected: True");

        //test the setImaginary() and setReal() methods
        x.setImaginary(2);
        x.setReal(5);

        //test the getImaginary() and getReal() methods
        System.out.println(x.getImaginary());
        System.out.println("Expected: 2");

        System.out.println(x.getReal());
        System.out.println("Expected: 5");

        //test the equals method again
        System.out.println(x.equals(y));
        System.out.println("Expected: False");

        //test the add method
        Complex added=x.add(y);
        System.out.println(added.getReal());
        System.out.println("Expected: 28.2");

        System.out.println(added.getImaginary());
        System.out.println("Expected: 35.1");



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I just posted both of the classes.

Comment: What line does it give you the error? In your partial stack trace it gave us a line number, but that line appears to be a comment.

Comment: The error happens when the equals method is first used.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the way you are building and/or running your code.  On OSX you are *somehow* running using an old `Complex.class` file that doesn't match the source code, and doesn't match what the `ComplexTest.class` file *expects*.

- This could be happening because you are not rebuilding properly.
- It could be happening because you have an old copy of `Complex.class` on your runtime classpath.

---

FWIW:

1. The "Complex.equals(LComplex;)Z" string means that the JVM expects to find a method with this signature in the `Complex` class:

   ```
    boolean equals(Complex)
   ```

   This method is present in the `Complex` source code ...
2. If you intended it to overload the `Object.equals(Object)` method, your `equals` method is incorrect.  (That's a different problem though ...)

Comment: How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: 1) Figure out whether the problem is incorrect build procedure or an incorrect runtime classpath.  2) Correct the build procedure or the classpath. 3)  Check that you haven't put your classes into the "endorsed" directories ... as suggested by trashgod.

Comment: Where is java.ext.dirs located on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing x.setImaginary(2); x.setReal(5); to x.setImaginary(2.0); x.setReal(5.0);. Maybe the version of java on the mac is requiring a double not an int.

Comment: It is nothing to do with the Java version.  Trust me.  That code is compatible with all versions since Java 1.0.